# Using a List as ComboBoxModel

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, comboboxmodel

I have a `LinkedList` of objects which is often changed by another thread and I also have a `JComboBox` which should show all these objects synchronous to the state of the list.

What is the best way to do this? I think I have to deal with a `ComboBoxModel`, but how can I use a reference in the model to the list?

Or do I understand something wrong and it's not so complicated as I think?

Comment: java.util.List for AbstractListModel, I'm sure that a few times here with good, clear description and/or with code in SSCCE/MCVE form

Comment: Use [Glazed Lists](http://www.glazedlists.com/) Luke